# Limit to two results for each individual ID

Tags: mysql

How would I return two results for each individual `meeting.id`?

I've tried things like `Row_Count()` and `Rank()` but they seem to cause syntax errors.

This is my query which I need adapting to show the two results per `meeting.id`.

```
    SELECT meeting_appointment.* FROM `meeting` 
    INNER JOIN meeting_appointment ON ( 
        meeting_appointment.meeting_id = meeting.id AND meeting_appointment.pupil_id = 0 AND meeting_appointment.guardian_id = 0 AND meeting_appointment.deleted = 0 
    ) 
    WHERE ( 
        meeting.grade_id = "-1" OR meeting.grade_id IN ('87') 
    ) 
    AND meeting.startTime < '2016-10-06 14:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND meeting.startTime > '2016-10-06 14:00:00' - INTERVAL 1 HOUR

    GROUP by meeting_appointment.id 
    ORDER BY meeting_appointment.startTime ASC
```

Comment: You may need to use a `UNION` to do this.

Comment: @CptMisery why `UNION`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your meeting_appointment.id are consecutive then this should show the first two 
meeting_appointment.id per meeting.id:

```
SELECT meeting_appointment.* FROM `meeting` 
INNER JOIN meeting_appointment ON (meeting_appointment.meeting_id = meeting.id)

WHERE (meeting.grade_id = "-1" OR meeting.grade_id IN ('87')) 
AND meeting.startTime < '2016-10-06 14:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND meeting.startTime > '2016-10-06 14:00:00' - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
AND meeting_appointment.pupil_id = 0 
AND meeting_appointment.guardian_id = 0 
AND meeting_appointment.deleted = 0 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM meeting_appointment ma WHERE ma.id<meeting_appointment.id-1
    AND ma.pupil_id = 0 
    AND ma.guardian_id = 0 
    AND ma.deleted = 0
)
GROUP by meeting_appointment.id 
ORDER BY meeting_appointment.startTime ASC
```

If you meeting_appointment.id are just random or non-numeric then it might need some tweaks but in order to code those teaks we'll need to know a bit more about the schema.

Comment: I get error saying "#1054 - Unknown column 'ma' in 'where clause'"

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an aggregate function, so `GROUP BY` is redundant. Remove that, and add a `LIMIT` clause, and you should be good to go:

```
SELECT ma.*
FROM meeting m
INNER JOIN meeting_appointment ma ON ma.meeting_id = m.id
WHERE m.grade_id IN ('-1','87')
AND ma.pupil_id = 0
AND ma.guardian_id = 0
AND ma.deleted = 0 
AND m.startTime < '2016-10-06 14:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
AND m.startTime > '2016-10-06 14:00:00' - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
ORDER BY ma.startTime ASC
LIMIT 2;
```

You could also use `BETWEEN` for the `datetime` column.

Comment: The above query will limit the overall result by 2. I doubt the OP has asked to limit results for each individual meeting.id by 2.

Comment: I see the question now. I think the problem is then similar to http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results... So now I am thinking, how big are the result sets going to be? If it's not too large, you're going to get a big speedup by simply getting the required IDs and doing something with them... might be useful to understand how this'll be used in practice.

Comment: @Eugene - The stackoverflow link you provided me with the answer I needed. I'm going to use `UNION_ALL`